# java heap allocation: error during initialization of VM for different user

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, java-6

I receive error message while running App with userA which exceeding 1800Mb heap , but the same App works fine with userB,

That's said, below command works for userA, but for userB there is an error

```
java -Xmx2048m -jar App
```

error:
Error occured during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space of VM
Could not create Java virtual machine

Comment: Does UserB have a `32-bit` Java installation?

Comment: If you use a 32-bit JVM your memory size is limited by how much the OS allows. This can be up to 3 GB on Unix, but as low as 1.2 GB on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For userB can you check the free memory available for execution ? This could be done by checking free -m on Linux or you could check what other application/processes are consuming resources using top command.

On windows you could verify with the task manager.

Comment: both users are on unix. Thanks for answer. Is there any option to tweak except killing processes?

Comment: A simple shell script to get the free memory and add a threshold based check. start the java process from within the shell script using the parameterised memory arguments

A simple way to extract the free memory could be 

free -m | awk  '{print $3}' | head -2 | tail -1

Comment: thanks. Any other commands could help except top and free? seems top/free are not available, but vmstat and sar -r work ( I use old solaris with limited commands£

Comment: vmstat -s   gives you a lot of relevant output similar to free command.

Please checkout this link 
http://serverfault.com/questions/38065/how-to-get-memory-usage-with-vmstat